# How to remove the "Running head" from papaja in Rstudio

Tags: r, papaja

I'm writing an essay on APA template using papaja package in Rstudio. When I finished editing the short title and knit it for pdf to have a look. The "Running head" of "Running head: Short Title" still remain in the top like this.

[image]

Is the "running head" text a part of the APA template? How could I remove it?

I want to get rid of the "running head" text in the red box. So in the final edition there will be no "running head" text in the "running head" part. There will only be the short title in it.

Comment: Please consider making this question reproducible

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the file apa6_man.docx in this folder --
\papaja\rmarkdown\templates\apa6\resources

Open it and replace the text "Running head: TITLE" in the header with a space.

Comment: While this works, it doesn't quite fit the question, because this will remove the header entirely. If you just get rid of `Running head: ` and keep `TITLE` it should work as intended. Also, I wouldn't recommend editing the package resources. Rather you should copy the file to the project directory and specify it as `reference_docx` in the YAML front matter.

Answer (score 0):

What Jeff suggests is a solution that should work for Word documents (see my addition in the comments). For PDF documents you can achieve this by adding a LaTeX command to an element on the title page (for example the author note, see [this SO question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/283448/apa6-package-in-man-mode-getting-rid-of-running-head-on-first-page):

```
authornote: |
  \thispagestyle{otherpage}

  Enter author note here.
```