# Suppress the Running Head when using papaja?

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio, papaja

I am trying to supress the running head on a pdf render of a manuscript written with `papaja`. Commenting out or deleting the `shorttitle` from the YAML (see below) both insert "Running head: SHORT TITLE" in the pdf header. Is there a way to completely eliminate it? Rendering as `classoption: "doc"` removes it from the first page, but not the subsequent pages.

```
---
title             : "The paper title"
# shorttitle        : "running head"

author: 
  - name          : "First Author"
    affiliation   : "1"
  
affiliation:
  - id            : "1"
    institution   : "Department of Science"

floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : yes
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : no
mask              : no
draft             : no
documentclass     : "apa6"
classoption       : "man, donotrepeattitle" # suppresses title on 1st page of MS
output: papaja::apa6_pdf
---




# Methods
We report how we determined our sample size, all data exclusions (if any), all manipulations, and all measures in the study. <!-- 21-word solution (Simmons, Nelson & Simonsohn, 2012; retrieved from http://ssrn.com/abstract=2160588) -->
```

NB: I am aware of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74309220/how-to-remove-the-running-head-from-papaja-in-rstudio) question/answer but it's not a general solution.

**EDIT:** I figured out how to use package `fancyheader` to remove from the main document, but the running head and page number remain on the cover page.

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \fancyhead[L]{}
  - \fancyhead[R]{}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \pagestyle{empty}
  - \thispagestyle{empty}
```

Did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think when using the `fancyhdr` package, we need to make sure that both the plain and fancy page styles are accounted for. Because the first page of a document often uses the plain page style by default.

Maybe you can try codes like:

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage{fancyhdr}
  - \pagestyle{fancy}
  - \fancyhead{}
  - \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  - \fancypagestyle{plain}{
      \fancyhead{}
      \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
    }
```

This code does the following:

- `\pagestyle{fancy}` applies the fancy page style to all pages, not just the first one.
- `\fancyhead{}` clears all header fields for the fancy page style.
- `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` removes the header line for the fancy page style.
- `\fancypagestyle{plain}{...}` redefines the plain page style, which is often used for the first page.
- Inside this command, `\fancyhead{}` and `\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}` do the same for the plain page style.

Comment: It didn't work, but sent me in the right direction. Answer below...thanks.